# Embedding HTML page in Email Body After Jenkins Build Completes

Tags: html, jenkins

I have a Jenkins automated testing job that creates some html pages and resources in order to display the test results. The main html test results page that displays the test results references some other locally generated files and an image from google. Is it possible for me to embed and display the main html page in the body of an email sent by the Jenkins job. The html page should work as it normally does if it is being viewed in a browser, including referencing the other generated resources in order to show the test results. Sample generated HTML from the main html test results page is shown below.

```
<html><head><title>Expando Framework Test Execution Report - BLEG Consumer</title><script src='res/tablefilter_all_min.js' type='text/javascript'></script><script src='res/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script><script src='res/script.js' type='text/javascript'></script><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='res/style.css' /><script type='text/javascript'>init();</script></head><body><h1 style='text-align:center; color:#971D31;'>Test Execution Report</h1><table border='1' style='font-family:tahoma; font-weight:bold; font-size:8pt; color:#4c4c4c' align='center' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='1'> <tbody>   <tr>        <td colspan='2' style='text-align:center; font-size: 12pt'>BLEG Consumer - Automation Execution Summary</td>    </tr>   <tr>        <td colspan='2' style='text-align:center'><img src='https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=350x100&chd=t:4,0,0,0&cht=p3&chl=Pass-4|Fail-0|NoRun-0|NotCompleted-0&chco=00FF00|FF0000|483D8B|FF8C00' /></td>  </tr>   <tr>        <td colspan='2' />  </tr>   <tr>        <td width='50%'>START TIME</td>         <td width='50%'>2017-08-23 04:04:42 PM</td>     </tr>   <tr>        <td>END TIME</td>       <td>2017-08-23 04:05:16 PM</td>     </tr>   <tr>        <td>DURATION</td>       <td>00:00:34</td>   </tr>   <tr>        <td colspan='2' />  </tr>   <tr>        <td>TOTAL TESTCASES</td>        <td>4</td>  </tr>   <tr style='color:green'>        <td>PASSED</td>         <td>4</td>  </tr>   <tr style='color:green'>        <td>PASS %</td>         <td>100.00</td>     </tr>   <tr style='color:red'>      <td>FAILED</td>         <td>0</td>  </tr>   <tr style='color:red'>      <td>FAIL%</td>      <td>0.00</td>   </tr>   <tr style='color:darkslateblue'>        <td>NORUN</td>      <td>0</td>  </tr>   <tr style='color:darkslateblue'>        <td>NORUN %</td>        <td>0.00</td>   </tr>   <tr style='color:darkorange'>       <td>NOTCOMPLETED</td>       <td>0</td>  </tr>   <tr style='color:darkorange'>       <td>NOTCOMPLETED %</td>         <td>0.00</td>   </tr> </tbody> </table> <!--   Host : AN00621276.eis.equifax.com   Host IP : 172.17.193.47   User : kxi6   --><br /><br /><!--<div style='width:100; bottom:10; right:10; position:fixed; color:green; font-family:Arial; font-size:10;'><marquee>&copy; 2016 Expando&trade; Framework by Shalvin Abraham</marquee></div>--><table id='report' border='1' style='width:100%'><thead><th>Project</th><th>Testcase ID</th><th>Status</th><th>Comment</th><th>Execution Time</th><th>Requests</th><th>Responses</th><th>Query Results</th></thead><tbody>
<tr><td>BLEGCommercial</td><td>BLEG_COMMERCIAL_SUBMIT_1</td><td><font color='green'>PASS</font></td><td style='text-align:left'><div style='text-align:center'>All Assertions are <font color='green'>PASS</font></span></td><td>2017-08-23<br style='mso-data-placement:same-cell;' />16:04:43</td><td><a target='_blank' href='BLEGCommercial/Request_BLEGCommercial_BLEG_COMMERCIAL_SUBMIT_1_S1_20170823.160443.407.xml'> click here </a></td><td><a target='_blank' href='BLEGCommercial/Response_BLEGCommercial_BLEG_COMMERCIAL_SUBMIT_1_S1_20170823.160443.407.xml'> click here </a></td><td><a target='_blank' href='BLEGCommercial/QueryResult_BLEGCommercial_BLEG_COMMERCIAL_SUBMIT_1_S2_20170823.160443.407.xml'> click here </a></td></tr>
<tr><td>BLEGCommercial</td><td>BLEG_COMMERCIAL_SUBMIT_2</td><td><font color='green'>PASS</font></td><td style='text-align:left'><div style='text-align:center'>All Assertions are <font color='green'>PASS</font></span></td><td>2017-08-23<br style='mso-data-placement:same-cell;' />16:04:50</td><td><a target='_blank' href='BLEGCommercial/Request_BLEGCommercial_BLEG_COMMERCIAL_SUBMIT_2_S1_20170823.160450.436.xml'> click here </a></td><td><a target='_blank' href='BLEGCommercial/Response_BLEGCommercial_BLEG_COMMERCIAL_SUBMIT_2_S1_20170823.160450.436.xml'> click here </a></td><td><a target='_blank' href='BLEGCommercial/QueryResult_BLEGCommercial_BLEG_COMMERCIAL_SUBMIT_2_S2_20170823.160450.436.xml'> click here </a></td></tr>
<tr><td>BLEGConsumer</td><td>BLEG_CONSUMER_SUBMIT_1</td><td><font color='green'>PASS</font></td><td style='text-align:left'><div style='text-align:center'>All Assertions are <font color='green'>PASS</font></span></td><td>2017-08-23<br style='mso-data-placement:same-cell;' />16:04:57</td><td><a target='_blank' href='BLEGConsumer/Request_BLEGConsumer_BLEG_CONSUMER_SUBMIT_1_S1_20170823.160457.166.xml'> click here </a></td><td><a target='_blank' href='BLEGConsumer/Response_BLEGConsumer_BLEG_CONSUMER_SUBMIT_1_S1_20170823.160457.166.xml'> click here </a></td><td><a target='_blank' href='BLEGConsumer/QueryResult_BLEGConsumer_BLEG_CONSUMER_SUBMIT_1_S2_20170823.160457.166.xml'> click here </a></td></tr>
<tr><td>BLEGConsumer</td><td>BLEG_CONSUMER_SUBMIT_2</td><td><font color='green'>PASS</font></td><td style='text-align:left'><div style='text-align:center'>All Assertions are <font color='green'>PASS</font></span></td><td>2017-08-23<br style='mso-data-placement:same-cell;' />16:05:10</td><td><a target='_blank' href='BLEGConsumer/Request_BLEGConsumer_BLEG_CONSUMER_SUBMIT_2_S1_20170823.160510.225.xml'> click here </a></td><td><a target='_blank' href='BLEGConsumer/Response_BLEGConsumer_BLEG_CONSUMER_SUBMIT_2_S1_20170823.160510.225.xml'> click here </a></td><td><a target='_blank' href='BLEGConsumer/QueryResult_BLEGConsumer_BLEG_CONSUMER_SUBMIT_2_S2_20170823.160510.225.xml'> click here </a></td></tr>
</tbody></table><script type='text/javascript'>var tf = setFilterGrid('report', getTableProps()); last();</script><div id='last'/></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) to send emails notifications.

It gives more control in 3 areas: Triggers, Content, Recipients

For your query, it supports sending emails with HTML content. For further more info please go through the documentation of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to embed HTML using the FILE variable in the body of the email.

${FILE,path="path to html file"}